# How do you insert data from a DropDownList, Calendar selection, and text box to SQL database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have followed the  SqlDataSource.Insert Method but have not been able to make it work. This is a DOT net 4.5 web forms application. My data base shows that a record has been added but there is no data transferred to the record. Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"CodeBehind="TimeLog.aspx.cs" Inherits="Goings_on.TimeLog" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#EDE174" BorderWidth="5px" BorderColor="#00CC00">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">


                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Employee Id"></asp:Label>
                <br/>

                <asp:TextBox ID="EmpId" runat="server" Width="147px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                    id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                    runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="EmpId"
                    Display="Static"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter Employee ID."/>

                <br/>

                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Type Of Route"></asp:Label>

                <br/>

                <asp:DropDownList ID="TypeOfRoute" runat="server" BackColor="White" Width="125px" Height="35px" DataValueField="Id_Type" ToolTip="Please indicate the route type!">
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Regular</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Homeless</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Special</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Field Trip</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                    id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
                    runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="TypeOfRoute"
                    Display="Static"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter type of route."/>

                <br/>

                <asp:TextBox ID="GetDate" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="177px" BorderColor="Yellow" Font-Size="Small" BackColor="White"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/CalendarIcon.png" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click1" Height="35px" ImageAlign="AbsBottom"/>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
                &nbsp;
                <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Day"
                              BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#003399" Height="225" Width="225" OnDayRender="AttachHolidays" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged">

                    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#00CC00" ForeColor="#336666" Height="1px"/>
                    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF"/>
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999"/>
                    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#66FFFF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99"/>
                    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666"/>
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="#003399" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" Height="25px"/>
                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCFF33" ForeColor="White"/>
                    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF"/>

                </asp:Calendar>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
                <asp:Button ID="AmButton" runat="server" Text="AM Route" Width="225px" Height="35px" OnClick="AmButton_Click"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="AM Hour_Min In" Width="225px"></asp:Label>
                <br/>

                <div>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource10" DataTextField="AMhour" DataValueField="AMhour" Width="80px" BackColor="White" Height="20px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource10" DataTextField="AMminutes" DataValueField="AMminutes" Width="80px" BackColor="White" Height="20px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
            <asp:Label ID="SubmitInfo"
                       runat="server"
                       Text="SubmittedInfo">
            </asp:Label>

            <asp:SqlDataSource
                ID="SqlDataSource10"
                runat="server"
                connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Goings_OnConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT AMminutes, AMhour FROM ClockTime"
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO DayClockTime (Id_Employee, Id_Type, Id_Date, AmHoOut, AmMinOut) VALUES (@EmpId, @TypeOfRoute , @GetDate, @AmHoO, @AmMinO)">
                <insertparameters>
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="EmpId" FormField="EmpId"/>
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="TypeOfRoute" FormField="TypeOfRoute"/>
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="GetDate" FormField="GetDate"/>
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="AmHoO" FormField="DropDownList1"/>
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="AmMinO" FormField="DropDownList2"/>

                </insertparameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <br/>
            <asp:Button ID="TimeSubmit"
                        runat="server"
                        OnClick="TimeSubmit_Click"
                        Text="Insert Clock Time"
                        Width="163px"/>
        </div>

        <p>
            &nbsp;
        </p>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

---

```
 protected void TimeSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                SqlDataSource10.Insert();
        }
```

Comment: "data base shows that a record has been added but there is no data transferred to the record" - This is little confusing. Did you query the table at the backend? Are you getting any errors? Please provide some more info.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have solved this problem. I found out you can not just insert the form code file. It must be enclosed with the traditional html/body tags. The .aspx files do not require the html/body tags because they have a master.site page. Now I will have to make either a menu in the file to return to the master site or just have a back button on the page.